# export gcc flags though catkin? CFG_EXTRAS?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the gcc c++0x flag set for a few of my packages. All the packages that depend on these package also needs the c++0x flag if they must not throw warning when the header files are processed.

Is there a way for catkin to export the flags? I saw the CFG_EXTRAS option for catkin_package(), Do I set the CFG_EXTRAS? What does it stand for?

Thanking you,
Benzun

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173947/export-gcc-flags-though-catkin?-cfg_extras?/) by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pass multiple "CMake configuration extra" files via `catkin_package(CFG_EXTRAS)` to be included when downstream packages find your package:

```
catkin_package(
  CFG_EXTRAS ${PROJECT_NAME}-extras.cmake
)
```

An example for such a file would be `cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}-extras.cmake`:

```
#  for older versions of clang, libstdc++ is used by default and we need to explicitly request libc++ instead
if(APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif ()
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Corbett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2912/jeremy-corbett/) on 2014-10-12**:
I think the cmake file must be saved with the ".in" extension i.e. cmake/$PROJECT_NAME-extras.cmake.in. I couldn't get it to work with just .cmake

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-13**:
Using only the extension ".cmake" is supported. E.g. the following package does exactly that: https://github.com/ros/class_loader